# VMWare bridged network works partially - is it a bug or a feature?

Tags: networking

It's my first question on StackExchange and I am more than happy to be here. I have an issue with my VMWare network configuration.

Namely, it works... partially. I tried searching for questions regarding the same thing, yet it was too difficult to me to formulate it properly. So, getting to the point, either I don't understand something or something's up with my bridged network configuration. Let me firstly show my network config and then, list what I can do and what I can't do:

Config: cable Internet (IP: A) -> router (subnet, computers with IPs: B1, B2 and B3, all ports forwarded from A to C) -> switch -> physical computer (IP: B3) -> virtual machine (IP: C) (VMWare Workstation 15). The connection between my computer and the virtual machine installed on it is bridged. The problem I am encountering is that I can't do the following:

If, being on the host computer with IP B3, I make an attempt to connect to C, using IP A (the public IP, given by the ISP), it shows a timeout.

On the other hand, if I try to connect to C from any other device, be it inside or outside the B subnet (B1, B2 or any device in the Internet), using IP A, it just works. It does connect. It just won't allow me to connect to C, using the A IP, only from the host computer. It is most surprising to me.
I'm sorry if you couldn't get it, please inform me about any corrections I can make to this question to make it comfort more to the community standards or, simply, make it clearer. Thanks in advance for any responses.

Comment: The services I would like to host on my virtual machine are Jira, Confluence, Bitbucket and Jenkins, by the way. Maybe it has something to do with the case?

Comment: SSH also behaves this way.